# HTML Data Attribute Value jQuery Object

Tags: jquery, html, json

How can I use an HTML attribute value as a JQuery object with `$.param`?

```
<div data-sd="{a:1,b:1,c:2}"></div>
```

When I try this I got strange results.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var v = $.param($('div').data('sd'));
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain 'strange results' and what you are expecting?

Comment: @dSquared: Since `data-sd` is not a well-formed JSON object, `$.param` will actually try to *convert* the string `"{a:1,b:1,c:2}"`, yielding `0=%7B&1=a&2=%3A&3=1&4=%2C&5=b&6=%3A&7=1&8=%2C&9=c&10=%3A&11=2&12=%7D` instead of `a=1&b=1&c=2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your object's property names with **double-quotes**, in order to have *well-formed* [JSON](http://json.org/):

```
<div data-sd='{"a":1,"b":1,"c":2}'></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Then, `$.param` will return `a=1&b=1&c=2`, as expected. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yn7HD/)**.

From **[HTML5 data-* Attributes](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)**:

> When the data attribute is an **object** (starts with '{') or array
>   (starts with '[') then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the string;
>   it must follow valid JSON syntax **including quoted property names**.